# Сократить PHP код

Tags: php

Есть вот такой код:

```
            $value = 1;
            $pig1_num = array(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,24,26,28);
            $pig2_num = array(1,3,5,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29);

            if (in_array($value, $pig1_num))
            {         
                $color_win = 'pig1';
                $multipler = 2;           
            }
            elseif (in_array($value, $pig2_num))
            {   
                $color_win = 'pig2';
                $multipler = 2;      
            }
            else
            { 
                $color_win = 'pig3';
                $multipler = 3;
            }

            return array($color_win, $multipler);
```

0 <= $value <= 29

Хочется как-то его облагородить/сократить, у кого-то есть идеи ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$value = 1;     
$color_win = 'pig3';
$multipler = 3;

$cond = $value >= 0 && $value <= 29 && $value != 7 && $value != 22;
if ($cond) {        
    $color_win = ($value % 2 == 0) ? 'pig1' : 'pig2';
    $multipler = 2; 
}

return array($color_win, $multipler);
```

но это только из логики, которую увидел лично я

Comment: Вы видно проглядели pig3, pig3 это цифры 7 и 22, они не выходят в 2 первых массива

Comment: @LorDo ну значит надо добавить в `if` еще это условие